# Update active item in menu with React and Semantic-Ui

Tags: reactjs, jsx, semantic-ui, react-router-dom

How can i change an item in the menu to be set to active item?
Currently the first item "Home" is always set to be active item. The goal is that if I click on of the other items, then that item will be set to active and the other item will no longer be active.

```
return (
            <div className="ui menu">
                <Link to="/">
                    <img 
                    style={{
                        padding: 20
                    }}
                    className="ui image" 
                    src={Rmarketingv1}
                    alt="alt"
                    />
                </Link>
                <div 
                    style={{
                        margin: 40
                    }}
                    className="ui borderless horizontal right secondary menu"
                    >
                    <div className="active item">
                        <Link to="/">
                            <h2>
                                Home
                            </h2>
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                    <div className="item">
                        <Link to="/Service">
                            <h2>
                                Tjenester
                            </h2>
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                    <div className="item">
                        <Link to="/work">
                            <h2>
                                Jobbmuligheter
                            </h2>
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                    <div className="item">
                        <Link to="/contact">
                            <h2>
                                Kontakt
                            </h2>
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

React router feeatures a `<NavLink>` property which features an `activeClassName` property. So to make things work, change your `<Links>` like this:

```
<div className="item">
    <NavLink to="/" activeClassName="active">
        <h2>
            Home
        </h2>
    </NavLink>
</div>
```

Disclaimer: This will set the "active" class to your  element and not your div like in your example above. Make sure to adjust the css code as well!

Answer (score 1):

You can just make use of `NavLink` instead of `Link`. you can give it an `activeClassName` prop and whenever the route matches `to` prop that className will be added to that link.

read the documentation here:
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/NavLink.md

Comment: How exact would I go about implementing this?

Comment: just import NavLink and use it instead of Link, and add an activeClassName="some-semantic-ui-class". or if you want to add your own styles, add a custom class and go to your style files and write some css to style that className.